# Speeding Up NumPy Array Reshape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text

I am looking for a way to speed up the reshaping of a 1-column text file to a 3D numpy array.

**Python Code:**

```
import numpy as np

nx = 1799
ny = 1059
num = 6

in_file = "data.txt"

arr = np.loadtxt(in_file)

reshaped_data = np.reshape(arr, (nx, ny, num))
print(reshaped_data)
```

`data.txt`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/198RLSR5JpDn3nESWQiOPiYBWxzazbUCs/view?usp=sharing

*`data.txt` is a 1-column text file (with 11,430,846 lines) that is six concatenated text files that each had an original shape of 1799x1059.*

My process is getting the 11,430,846 values into the correct shape (1799x1059x6).

Currently, this reshaping process is taking about 25 seconds to complete. I would like to get it down to <10 seconds.

Comment: save your text file  as a numpy file using np.save() and read in the resulting file using np.load()  - the reshape isn't taking any time at all, it's reading and parsing the text file that is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I did some testing. In the code you provided, almost all of the execution time is for `arr = np.loadtxt(in_file)` and the reshape is completed almost instantaneously. Test code:

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter

nx = 1799
ny = 1059
num = 6

t = perf_counter()
arr = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
print(f'Loading time: {round(perf_counter() - t, 3)}')

t = perf_counter()
reshaped_data = np.reshape(arr, (nx, ny, num))
print(f'Reshaping time: {round(perf_counter() - t,3)}')
```

Outputs:

```
Loading time: 32.54
Reshaping time: 0.006
```

So, the problem is loading the data. You can improve that part by using pandas:

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
import pandas as pd

nx = 1799
ny = 1059
num = 6

t = perf_counter()
arr = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None).to_numpy().T
print(f'Loading time: {round(perf_counter() - t, 3)}')

t = perf_counter()
reshaped_data = np.reshape(arr, (nx, ny, num))
print(f'Reshaping time: {round(perf_counter() - t, 3)}')
```

Outputs:

```
Loading time: 0.753
Reshaping time: 0.007
```

Comment: thanks for the timings and the solution! (by the way pandas nowadays [recommends](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) `to_numpy()` instead of `values`  though it shouldn't make much difference in terms of performance here i guess).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Will `values` be dropped in a later version or is there some other reason?

Comment: In the [release notes of 0.24](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index) that introduced `to_numpy`, they essentially say `.values` might have some inconsistencies but they don't say it will be deprecated soon at all, so...